# How to change QWindow or QWidget without openning new form?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I have `QMainWindow`, and `QWidget` like :

```
 namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_actionUserAdd_triggered();

    void on_actionEditUser_triggered();

    void on_actionShow_User_triggered();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    EditUser *editUserWindow;
    ShowUser *showUserWindow;
};
```

QWidget is :

```
namespace Ui {
class EditUser;
}

class EditUser : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit EditUser(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~EditUser();

private:
    Ui::EditUser *ui;
};
```

And when actionEditUser is triggered I am creating new form:

```
editUserWindow = new EditUser();
editUserWindow->show();
```

However I do not want to open/create new form. I want to paste QWidget(EditUser) to `QMainWindow`. So that appliction can work on just 1 form, instead of 2,3 or more. Could you please kindly help me how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Qt` widget without parent is a separate window. So answer is simple: just set parent. For example:

```
editUserWindow = new EditUser(this);//inside mainwindow, mainwinodw is a parent of EditUser
editUserWindow->show();
```

But in this case `editUserWindow` will be placed at `0,0` position(in parent coordinates)(top left) , so you have 2 approaches. Use `setGeometry()` to set `x`,`y`, `width` and `height` of widget, and better approach: add this widget to your current layout.

Comment: Yes, it works but, when Qwidget is placed on QMainwindow, toolbar which is placed on QMainWindow not works anymore.

Comment: Ohh, it is also because of layout.. Thank you very much.